# Search is not working in ElasticSearch for words ending with 's' 'y' 'e'

Tags: java, elasticsearch, stemming

If search string and target object has any of following characters in the end then it doesn't work.
s y e

In our application if user's name Grann**y**, Smith. It was not searching any record for Granny as it ends with **y**. Same was case with s and e. i.e. James, Katie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of the issue is stemmer. As per elastic search docs, Algorithmic stemmers apply a series of rules to each word to reduce it to its root form.

For example, an algorithmic stemmer for English may remove the -s and -es suffixes from the end of plural words. You can refer to following sites for more detail:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/stemming.html#algorithmic-stemmers
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html#:~:text=Stemmer%20token%20filteredit,porter%20stemming%20algorithm%20for%20English](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html#:%7E:text=Stemmer%20token%20filteredit,porter%20stemming%20algorithm%20for%20English).

In your application mapping.json file you can remove if any stemmer configuration is already present.

```
"settings": {
"analysis": {
**// Remove whole filter element below. line# 4 to 9
  "filter": {
    "custom_english_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "name": "english"
    }
  },**
  "normalizer": {
    "useLowercase": {
      "type": "custom",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "custom_tokenizer": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 1,
      "max_gram": 10,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit"
      ]
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "NGram_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        **// Remove stemmer from filter below. line#35
        "custom_english_stemmer",**
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    },
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        **// Remove stemmer from filter below. line#44
        "custom_english_stemmer",**
        "asciifolding"
      ],
      "type": "custom"
    }
  }
},
"max_ngram_diff": "50"
```

}

If your application does not have any searchable description field which can have plural words then you can remove stemmer from your configuration and it should work fine.